# How to know that last recyclerView item of first or current screen/page is loaded, any Callbacks but gets called once?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, google-people-api

I am using a grid layout of recyclerView and have tried several options using either onLayoutCompled methods and also by onScollListner methods, tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151476/recyclerview-onscrolllistener-being-called-multiple-times-for-once-instance-of) answer but it's stiil calling multiple times as each item keeps loading, nothing is working.

Just want to detect the last recyclerView item **of the particular screen** is completely loaded or visible to the user according to their screen size Or we can say that when the user's current screen is full of the recyclerView Items, any way to detect that? ANd should be **called only once**. Any help would be great.
Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Sharedpref** value which can be set to true in your `onScrollStateChanged` method based on your condition.

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
   super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

   if (newState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
      return;
   }

   boolean isLastPositionVisible = mFollowingLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == getList().size() - 1

   if(isLastPositionVisible && getSharedPrefValue()) {
      // Call your method
      // Set sharedpref value to true.
   }

}
```

Comment: First of all thanx for replying. I do not want to wait for the list to end or complete, I want to detect if the current page is full and detect only once..